# Registered symbol in Write-Host: ISE vs Script

Tags: powershell, console

After some testing I have narrowed the issue WAY down, so I have revised this original post to only focus on the "real" issue. Which is, this code works just fine in the ISE

```
$string = "Autodesk®"
Write-Host $string
$string > C:\Test.txt
```

But when run as a script the Write-Host will represent the Registered symbol incorrectly. Test.txt is correct in both cases. This is the behavior in PS 2 and PS 4.

Comment: What is the "`OpenRemoteBaseKey` approach to creating XML"?

Comment: FWIW, an upgrade to PS 4.0 does not fix the issue. And I found reference to this: [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 which also doesn't fix the situation, but it is broken in a new way, the r is replaced with some other symbols when using [Console]::WriteLine(). So, it would seem this is at least a fruitful direction to pursue. Crossed fingers someone has a "Just do this!" solution forthcoming. ;)

Comment: Updated the OP to better represent what I now see is the "real" problem. I was testing one set of code (the OpenRemoteBaseKey approach) in the ISE and seeing it work, then running my code that uses native PS cmdlets as a script and seeing it not work. The issue wasn't the code, it was the environment running the code.

Answer (score 0):

So it would seem that the default font for the console doesn't include certain symbols, while the default font for the ISE does. And the font for the console can't be set with code. So, this is just an unsolvable bug. I guess I am using PowerShell more than a little "off label" since I am trying to actually do nicely formatted progress logging to the console, which is really more than it's intended for.